# Is it possible to ignore existing files in the directory when performing scp using gcloud compute scp?

Tags: gcloud, scp, gcloud-compute

I am using **gcloud compute scp** to copy a folder to the remote, this got terminated (reason unknown) after coping ~60% of the files. Now, is there anyway to copy the remaining files without overwriting the existing files in the remote. I would prefer skipping the current file if it's present in the remote.

I tried to use **gsutil** with **rsync**: this failed, as my destination is just a folder rather than a bucket.